# Linking WordPress Post Types to Another

Tags: custom-post-types

Suppose a movie and serial site created some new typing posts. For example one for the cast page and one for the film.
Is it possible for the movie edit page to be something like selecting a category to select another post type of actor, and the movie page displaying the name of the actor  with the image of the actor in the other post type? Also on the news page Select a news item (in another post type) to display the news title on the movie page.

Comment: Yes, you can e.g. store arrays of post IDs in post meta for these things. The ACF plugin might give you some of this out of the box (but I haven't used it with Gutenberg) but it's easy enough to code all of this up with category searches and post meta yourself.

Comment: @rup Thanks. Is this connection the best solution? Are you suggesting another solution to build a site similar to IMDB?

Comment: You mean storing arrays of post IDs? Well it's a solution. I guess you could add extra tables containing the mappings too, which might make more sense if you need bidirectional mappings easily, but that's less WordPress-like. I don't know what the best solution is sorry.